# all cinnamon fonts defect

Tags: cinnamon

All text in cinnemon is broken:

[image]

I already tried resetting cinnemon to defaults

```
dconf reset -f /org/cinnamon/
```

And tried this:

```
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.interface font-name

gsettings reset org.nemo.desktop font

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name

gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font
```

I restarted the computer. But I still got the same problem.

Unfortunately I cannot use a terminal.. well I can copy-paste commands, but I cannot read the output. :( Though, I can use `ctrl+alt+F1` where fonts are working.

I hence tried restoring via `timeshift --restore` to a snapshot 3 days back, but the problem persists.

I made some upgrades via the normal upgrade manager last night and also messed around with android studio and kvm which may have led to it.

What can I do?

- **Linux Mint** 19.3
- **Kernel** 5.4.0-52-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by downloading the Ubuntu Regular font from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu

I saved it under a file "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" so I can recognize it even with a broken font, opend the archive and clicked the UI buttons to install it.